# Rebind cursor movement in emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp

i am actually trying to customize my emacs keys for cursor movement. 
And what i want to archive is that when i enter M-+ or M-- that the 
cursor either moves to the end of line or to the beginning. And also 
i am trying to setup C-i for backward-paragraph and forward-paragraph.
What i thought should be done with some code in my .emacs file like this:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-k") 'forward-paragraph) 
(global-set-key (kbd "C-i") 'backward-paragraph) 
(global-set-key (kbd "M-+") 'back-to-indentation) 
(global-set-key (kbd "M--") 'end-of-line)
```

But unfortunately none of these global keys are working. Could someone give me a hint what i am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: How about `beginning-of-line` instead of `back-to-indentation`?  At any rate, your code works fine:  `(global-set-key (kbd "M-+") 'back-to-indentation)  (global-set-key (kbd "M--") 'end-of-line)`  If it's not working, try placing it at the very end of your configuration file.  If it works then, perhaps you have another configuration somewhere overriding it -- e.g., in a third-party library you've installed, or a particular mode that is active.  Go ahead and press `C-h k` and then the key bindings at issue to see what comes up -- perhaps it will show that something else is actually occurring.

Comment: Since local keymaps take precedence over global ones, you need to make sure that no local bindings exist for those keys. Use "describe-mode" to view the current local bindings. If you'd like to use your bindings above regardless of the local keymap, you need to use a different approach, such as putting your bindings in a new sparse keymap in a new minor mode that is always active.

Comment: Just wonder... Keys 'home' and 'end' on your keyboard don't work? As far as I know Ctrl-up and Ctrl-down help skip to beginning and to end of current paragraph respectively.

Comment: @Mark shure these keys work on my keyboard. But everytime i have to use them i have to move my right hand from my home position to the 'home' and 'end' key which is time consuming. And because of that i wanted to define some keys which are right next to the home position

Comment: @PolymathMonkey, I see ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative way to define key-bindings is to use vector notation:

```
(global-set-key [(control k)] 'forward-paragraph)
(global-set-key [(control i)] 'backward-paragraph)
(global-set-key [(meta ?+)] 'back-to-indentation)
(global-set-key [(meta ?-)] 'end-of-line)
```

I find this way more intuitive, and I have been using it for so many years now that I already forgot the caveats of "kbd notation"